# How can I exclude a global variable from rubocop?

Tags: ruby, global-variables, code-analysis, rubocop

I want to exclude a global variable from rubocop but I'm not being able to find the rule name. 
I tried adding

```
GlobalVars:
  Exclude:
    - redis
```

to `.rubocop.yml` but no luck.

The error says `Do not introduce global variables.`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Switch `Exclude` with [`AllowedVariables`](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/blob/0c8fcd343cec4bddeb60b8406775e1893318f907/lib/rubocop/cop/style/global_vars.rb#L57).

Comment: It works!! 
GlobalVars:
  AllowedVariables: 
    - $redis

Answer (score 9):

in `.rubocop.yml`:

```
GlobalVars:
  AllowedVariables:
    - $redis
```

Note that the variable name requires the leading dollar sign.